# how to adjust the printing page size to my barcode size in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

I have a barcode printer and a sticker roll, on which the printer is going to print the barcode. The size of each sticker is 2.5" * 1.5". I have already generated the barcode using a library now when I print this barcode, the browser is printing the whole page and not just the barcode I have tried different approaches like making a div and giving it the specific width/height and only printing that specific div but the problem is still the same.
.[image: I am attaching an image to make my problem clear]

Comment: Have you set the correct paper size, i.e.  2.5" * 1.5"? It looks like you're using Chrome, so you can find it, in your image, under "More settings".

Comment: @KIKOSoftware What do mean by setting the paper size? If you talking about the More Settings Dropdown (In the attached picture) there is no option to set custom page size. Currently, my page size is set to 2*4.

Comment: Yes, I meant the "More Settings Dropdown". The paper size there must match the size of paper you're using. If your size, 2.5" * 1.5, is not there, you can add it. This is usually done in the printer settings of the operating system.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I got it! Love you...... ❤

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem from @KIKO SOFTWARE:

In "More Settings Dropdown" the paper size must match the size of paper you're using. If your size (2.5" * 1.5) is not there, you can add it. This is usually done in the printer settings of the operating system.

Just go to Control Panel>Hardware and Sound>Devices and Printers

Right-click on your printer select "Printer Preferences" then in Page Setup click "New" and add your required size :(

**And here is the result**

[image]

Thanks to @KIKO SOFTWARE

Comment: It all makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).